# Source not available for newly opened window - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to automate a Web Application through Selenium. But at a point Im getting stuck. Problem is that when I open a page and click on Search (to load all the existing saved data), a new window opens where the F12 option is not working neither can I right click on that window and select view source. If I could get the source of that window, I can use window handle. Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Comment: Can you share some code of what you are trying?

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use something like this to a pop-up window:

```
public void switchToWindowOtherThan(String windowHandle) {

        try {
            for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

                if (!handle.equals(windowHandle)) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchWindowException nwe) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
```

In my code I would use it as follows:

```
switchToWindowOtherThan(driver.getWindowHandle());
```

Comment: I have tried this.. But for no success. It returns the values from the old window itself.. Here a new window opens up and I cannot get the source code of that particular window or elements.. That is the problem... For a normal window.. if I press F12, I would get the source code, but here its not the scenario..

Comment: Hi friends, Got the solution for this.. It was the problem of Internet explorer.. I just updated the version and now the source tracking working fine.. Thanks for your replies.